# c pipe why is fd[0] and fd[1] 3 and 4

Tags: c, linux, fork, pipe

I have a code segment below. I wanted to see what the vale of fd1 and fd0 are and in all the processes I created they end up being 3 and 4? Why is this.

```
  if (pipe(fd) < 0)
        printf("Pipe Error");
      if ((pid = fork()) < 0 )
      {
        printf("Fork Error");
      }
      else if (pid > 0) //daddy
      {
        close (fd[0]);
        write(fd[1],"Hi, Im Parent \n", 15);
        printf("Value of fd1 is %d and fd0 is %d in parent. \n", fd[1], fd[0]);
        printf("Parent Process is %d \n", pid);
        printf("My true id is: %d and my parent id is %d \n", getpid(), getppid());
        wait();
      }
```

Comment: 0,1,2 are already in use (stdin, stdout, stderr)

Comment: You don't include the definition of `fd*`, but clearly they are file descriptors. A file descriptor is a small integer that identifies a resource (the open file) hidden away in the kernel-- not a pointer or buffer.

Comment: What values do you expect?

Comment: Well I'm not entirely sure for what to expect. At first I thought maybe characters would be floating around. Matt cleared it up for me though

Answer (score 1):

File *descriptors* (returned from functions like `open` or `pipe`, though in different ways) are small integers representing an open file.

They are distinct from the concept of file *handles* which are a pointer to a `FILE` type in standard C (I use the term "handle", though the standard itself simply states it associates a pointer with a stream and returns that pointer).

Hence, you'd *expect* behaviour like what you're seeing, `pipe()` grabbing the first two descriptors not currently in use.

File descriptors `0`, `1` and `2`, refer to standard input, standard output and standard error respectively, similar to the `FILE *` values `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`.